# Date and Time in a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I really need  your help. I'd like to order and convert in axis my timestamp in order to plot my prices with timestamp in axis.

More exactly, I have :

```
price                               timestamp
89                                  22/01/2016 17:34
87                                  22/01/2016 16:28
78                                  22/01/2016 19:37
89                                  22/01/2016 11:20
```

And i'd like to get :

```
price                                 timestamp
89                                    22/01/2016 11:20
87                                    22/01/2016 16:28
78                                    22/01/2016 17:34
89                                    22/01/2016 19:37
```

After that, I'd like to plot (price,timestamp) with a good scale for the axis.

Thank you !

Comment: Take a look at `?order`

Comment: Is there a mistake in your example, or do you really want to sort only the second column? (In first one timestamp `22/01/2016 17:34` has price 89, but in second it's 78, and vice versa with `22/01/2016 19:37`).

Comment: Yes thank you're right, i'd like rather that :

price                               timestamp
89                                  22/01/2016 17:34
87                                  22/01/2016 16:28
78                                  22/01/2016 19:37
89                                  22/01/2016 11:20


price                                 timestamp
89                                    22/01/2016 11:20
87                                    22/01/2016 16:28
89                                   22/01/2016 17:34
78                                    22/01/2016 19:37